# Struts 2 s:select tag dynamic id

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts2, ognl

I have multiple fields of various types in a JSP page and one button.
These fields are generated based on the info got from a metadata table that I have created.

Since I don't know how many and what type of fields are present, **I am giving dynamic `id`'s to them**. I am using Struts 2 tags in my JSP.

The issue is with the `<s:select>` tag: when I give scriplet within the `id` attribute, it displays the following error :

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /success.jsp(83,12) quote symbol expected

```xml
<s:if test="%{#masterColDO.controlType=='dropdown'}">
    <s:select styleClass="login-textbox" 
                   style="width:130px"  
                    list="#masterColDO.validation"     
                    name="chngdColumnValues" 
                      id=<%="columnId" + count%> />
</s:if> 
<s:else>
    <input type=<s:property value="#masterColDO.controlType" /> 
          class="login-textbox " 
           name="chngdColumnValues" 
             id=<%="columnId" + count%> />
</s:else>
```

Javascript is as follows:

```js
var addUpdateBtnId = document.getElementById('addUpdateBtnId');
addUpdateBtnId.value='Update';
addUpdateBtnId.onclick = function() {
    onClickUpdateBtn(rowIndex);
};
var selectedUpdateRow = xmlhttp.responseText.split(",");
for(var i = 0; i < selectedUpdateRow.length; i++){
    var columnElementId = "columnId"+i;
    document.getElementById(columnElementId).value = selectedUpdateRow[i];
}
document.getElementById("columnId"+(primaryKeyPos-1)).readOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Scriptlet`s are the old way of doing things, [you should avoid writing `Java` code in `JSP`'s at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/1654265); 

Struts2 helps you achieving the same goals using its tags and `OGNL` only.

The `<input />` part is working because you are injecting a `scriptlet` inside an HTML tag, that is allowed.

The `<s:select />` part is not working because you are injecting a `scriptlet` inside an Struts2 tag, that is not allowed.

To make it work, you should use `#attr` syntax in `OGNL` to access the `Java` variables declared in `Scriptlets` and pushed *by you* in the `Page Context`, like this (completely untested):

```xml
<%
    for (int counter=0;counter<myList.size();counter++) {
       // pushing it into the pageContext
       pageContext.setAttribute("counter",counter);
%>
        <s:select cssClass="login-textbox" 
                  cssStyle="width:130px" 
                      list="#masterColDO.validation" 
                      name="chngdColumnValues"      
                        id="%{'columnId' + #attr['counter']}" />
<%    
    }
%>
```

However, even if it's technically possible, it is discouraged. You should use the pure Struts2 way for that, that would be the following:

```xml
<s:iterator value="myList" status="ctr">
    <s:select cssClass="login-textbox" 
              cssStyle="width:130px" 
                  list="#masterColDO.validation" 
                  name="chngdColumnValues" 
                    id="%{'columnId' + #ctr.index}" />
</s:iterator>
```

---

P.S: Struts tags doesn't have any `styleClass` attribute; you can use `cssClass` and/or `cssStyle`;

And, if `controlType` is a String, you should use `.equals` instead of `==`: `<s:if test="%{#masterColDO.controlType.equals('dropdown')}">`.

Answer (score 3):

You should rather use Struts2 expression syntax likes this:

```
id="%{'columnId' + count}"
```

Comment: In my code count is a JAVA variable. I am using it as a counter. i have instantiated it as  <% int count = 0;%> . I tried with the above piece of code,it's not working

Comment: This <input type=<s:property value="#masterColDO.controlType" /> class="login-textbox " name="chngdColumnValues" id=<%="columnId" + count%> />   works

Comment: Mixing scriplets with JSP tags is a bad practise, you should try to use <s:set/> or <s:iterator status="true"/> or define count as action's property
http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/iterator.html

Answer (score 0):

Struts2 usage valuestacks, So this count should be fetched in ognl manner,
try something like this:

```
id="%{'columnId'+count}"
```

Comment: In my code count is a JAVA variable. I am using it as a counter. I have instantiated it as <% int count = 0;%> . I tried with the above piece of code,it's not working.                               This <input type=<s:property value="#masterColDO.controlType" /> class="login-textbox " name="chngdColumnValues" id=<%="columnId" + count%> /> works