# How to set end attribute dynamically with Struts2 iterator in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, scriptlet, struts-tags

```jsp
<% 
    RegisterAction aro=new RegisterAction();    
    int count=aro.getLi().size();
%>

<s:iterator value="li" begin="0" end="1">
    <fieldset>
        name     : <s:property value="name"     /><br/>
        password : <s:property value="password" /><br/>
        email    : <s:property value="email"    /><br/>
        gender   : <s:property value="gender"   /><br/>
        country  : <s:property value="country"  /><br/>
    </fieldset>
</s:iterator>
```

How to set `end` attribute value dynamically for iteration, reading the `count` variable ?

If I use `end="<%=count%>"` this is not working.

If I use `end="count"` it's working but I am getting same result multiple of numbers if I refresh the page or reload.

Comment: By dynamically do you mean from some variable? Or from javascript?

Comment: You forgot one code line (your <h4>)

Comment: ya from some variable, which i initialized in jsp before iterator.

Comment: RegisterAction aro=new RegisterAction();

int count=aro.getLi().size(); ill have to use count variable in end attribute.

Comment: Just use your variable in `end` attribute.

Comment: ya i used there in <%=count%> but that is not working. is there anything to use apart from this...?

Comment: without expression tag if i use that count variable within end attribute in iterator, that is keep on show same result how many time we refresh that many number of rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `#attr` notation in OGNL to read variables set within Scritplet blocks, if you push them in the pageContext:

```jsp
<% 
    RegisterAction aro = new RegisterAction();
    int count = aro.getLi().size();
    pageContext.setAttribute("count", count); // pushing the variable into the pageContext
%>

<s:iterator value="li" begin="0" end="%{#attr['count']}">
    <fieldset>
        name     : <s:property value="name"     /><br/>
        password : <s:property value="password" /><br/>
        email    : <s:property value="email"    /><br/>
        gender   : <s:property value="gender"   /><br/>
        country  : <s:property value="country"  /><br/>
    </fieldset>
</s:iterator>
```

But **you should never use Scriptlet [for many reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/1654265)**.

It's also very easy to use Struts tags instead of scriptlets for your purposes, [like shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14644756/1654265).

---

**EDIT**:

> If I use `end="count"` it's working but I am getting same result multiple of numbers if I refresh the page or reload.

It's however unclear why you are instantiating an Action in a Scriptlet block, and then why you do expect the result of count to be different across the page loadings, since your code is always referring to a collection in its initial state.

If RegisterAction is **your current action**, then what you want is probably:

```jsp
<s:iterator value="li" begin="0" end="%{li.size()}">
```

that is in fact

```jsp
<s:iterator value="li">
```

and you are overcomplicating a simple iteration by factor 2337.

Comment: i tried this also but same how previously its keep on loading multiple number of same record after refresh and re-load like only working.

Comment: ya may be yours answer correct, ya i already tested above two answer but i expected some accurate answer over that prob. may be as u told collection keep on iteration from initial state.

Comment: @santosh, you expect an accurate answer to a completely unclear question ? ***What*** you want to achieve ***exactly*** ? Because (now) it seems you just need to iterate a collection. And if it is like that, the whole scriptlet question is irrelevant and misleading, even though if well answered. Just use iterator tag, witho no start nor end.

Comment: @ Andrea Ligios, ya i tried how u told, actually i m reading the data from db and set to list and printing, how many records there in db that much record only to display in jsp even afer refresh also, but here same record keep on displaying multiple number of time as how we refresh the page, and if we use integer value within end attribute that will work properly, then what is the use of that...? so i am thinking.

Answer (score 0):

hi lastly i got answers as how i want you can use this below code in action class for initialize arraylist  from db count

```
int l1=st.executeUpdate("select count(*) from strutsuser");
         li=new ArrayList<RegisterAction>(l1);
```

view jsp is

```
<s:iterator value="li" >

<fieldset >
name : <s:property value="name"/><br/>
password : <s:property value="password"/><br/>
email : <s:property value="email"/><br/>
gender : <s:property value="gender"/><br/>
country : <s:property value="country"/><br/>

</fieldset>

</s:iterator>
```

this will solve the number of multiple display of same record even if we refresh the page with struts iterator.